# Method not getting mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a method but the test is running the real method.

```
//Controller
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private Utils utils = new Utils();

    public String myMethod(String json){

        // Stuff gets done
        return utils.writeToKafka(topic, json, kafkatemplate, classname);

    }
```

I have a test class that looks like this:

```
//Test
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor;

    @Test
    public void processOSPUpdateRequested_test(){
         Controller controller = new Controller();
         Utils utils = Mockito.spy(new Utils());
         Mockito.doReturn("myResult").when(utils).writeToKafka(anyString(), anyString(), any(), anyString());

         String topic = controller.myMethod(myString);

         //Some assertions
```

My writeToKafka method signature is:

```
public String writeToKafka(String topic, String json, KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate, String classname)
```

However, when I run the test, writeTokafka is not mocked! It runs the actual method. Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Your controller has its own instance of `utils`. It doesn't have the one you spied.

Comment: @khelwood what would be the good practice here then? Using a singleton pattern?

Comment: Dependency injection is often used to address this kind of problem. Normally you wouldn't have your controller instantiating `Utils` itself: it would get it from somewhere you have access to so you can replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your problem:  you're `new`ing an instance of `Utils` and you can't cleanly get to it from your test.

There are two ways to go about fixing this - both come from a philosophical stance on whether or not you want to use mocks.  Both *do* require that you inject `Utils` and make it a bean somewhere.

1. Inject `Utils` and in your test, inject the mock, and *abandon* the Spring test runner.

   Once you have the mock in place, you would want to change your test around to *not* use the Spring runner, but to use the Mockito runner instead.

   ```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
   public class ControllerTest {
       @Mock
       private Utils utils;

       @InjectMocks
       private Controller testObj;

       // The rest of your test code
   }
   ```
2. Inject `Utils` into your test as a defined test-scope bean which exhibits the behavior you want under test.

   This is a bit more fiddly, but you get the ability to leverage the Spring test runner.  I leave this as an exercise for the reader (essentially, once you have the `Utils` bean written, writing another one for tests isn't difficult).